# Python - Adding values to a set that is not equal to the dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary, set, key

I have a function to make a complete graph. It takes an input that is an integer, n. The function is meant to return a dictionary, where keys are the nodes (0 to n-1), and values are sets with numbers that do not include the node. My function is currently this:

```
def make_complete_graph(num_nodes):

    new_dict = {}
    new_set = set([])

    for i in range(0, num_nodes):
        new_dict[i] = new_set


    for key, value in new_dict.items():
        for j in range(0, num_nodes):
            if j != key:
                value.add(j)

    return new_dict
```

but it returns:

```
{0: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, 1: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, 2: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, 3: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, 4: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}}
```

when I want it to return

```
{0: {1, 2, 3, 4}, 1: {0, 2, 3, 4}, 2: {0, 1, 3, 4}, 3: {0, 1, 2, 4}, 4: {0, 1, 2, 3}}
```

It seems to ignore the 
`if j != key` line. How do I go about resolving this?

Comment: You used the same set as every value.

Comment: Use: `new_dict[i] = new_set.copy()`

Answer (score 1):

You used the same set (`new_set`) as every value.

If you change

```
new_dict[i] = new_set
```

to

```
new_dict[i] = set()
```

then you'd have a different set at each value, and those sets can be updated independently.

Alternatively, you could simplify your whole code using comprehensions:

```
def make_complete_graph(num_nodes):
    return {key:{n for n in range(num_nodes) if n!=key} for key in range(num_nodes)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you use the same `set` for every value in your dictionary and all `add` operations are performed on the same `set`. The result is that all the values of your dict are equal to the set you declared with all the modifications that you made for it.

As a side note, you can accomplish your task without the first loop:

```
def make_complete_graph(num_nodes):
    new_dict = {}
    for i in range(num_nodes):
        new_dict[i] = set(filter(lambda x: x!=i, range(num_nodes)))
    return new_dict

print(make_complete_graph(5))
# output: {0: {1, 2, 3, 4}, 1: {0, 2, 3, 4}, 2: {0, 1, 3, 4}, 3: {0, 1, 2, 4}, 4: {0, 1, 2, 3}}
```